# How to use click event with Bootstrap-Vue <b-nav-item-dropdown> in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue, vue-events

How do I use the click event with the `<b-nav-item-dropdown>` in Bootstrap-Vue shown below? I checked out the Vue.js documentation but I am not able to find any click event for `<b-nav-item-dropdown>`.

```html
<b-nav-item-dropdown text="nav_title">
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">
        a
    </b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">
        a
    </b-dropdown-item>
</b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Use `show` or `shown`

The [`<b-nav-item-dropdown>`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/nav#comp-ref-b-nav-item-dropdown) in [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/) has no `click` event, but emits an event called [`show`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/nav#comp-ref-b-nav-item-dropdown-events) just before the dropdown is shown, including when it is clicked.  It emits [`shown`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/nav#comp-ref-b-nav-item-dropdown-events) right after.

```html
<b-nav-item-dropdown @show="doSomething">
```

Your code:

```html
<b-nav-item-dropdown text="nav_title" @show="doSomething">
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">
        a
    </b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">
        a
    </b-dropdown-item>
</b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

```js
methods: {
  doSomething() {
    console.log('shown');
  }
}
```

(You didn't find information for it on Vue's site because they didn't make the library.)